# Embedded Jasper Reports not working due to font issues on Ubuntu (JBoss 7)

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, awt, jboss7.x

I recently deployed my web application (which runs on JBoss7, Java 7) on a local ubuntu server (Linux 2.6.32-31-server #61-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 19:44:42 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Since then, I've been getting all kinds of exceptions when I try to run reports on my applications. The application uses Jasper Reports and this is the exception I'm seeing ...

`Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Problem    reading font data.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.(SimpleFontFace.java:109) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.(SimpleFontFace.java:129) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.getInstance(SimpleFontFace.java:68) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFamily.setNormal(SimpleFontFamily.java:99) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:261) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:232) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:193) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:162) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.(JRStyledTextParser.java:83) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    ... 36 more`

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:967) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.(SimpleFontFace.java:101) [jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.0.jar:4.7.0]
    ... 46 more

I'm unable to figure out what is causing the IOException which is preventing the reading of font data. Any help is much appreciated.